# Inflating a TextView and an ImageView within a LinearLayout from a RecyclerView

Tags: android

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> mTrailers;
private Context mContext;


// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MovieAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> trailers) {
    mTrailers = trailers;
    mContext = context;
}


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.trailer_view, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

public void watchYoutubeVideo(String id) {
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
    try {
        mContext.startActivity(appIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        mContext.startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}


// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
    holder.mTextView.setText("Trailer " + (position + 1));
    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            watchYoutubeVideo(mTrailers.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    });
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mTrailers.size();
}


// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mImageView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.play_button_image_view);
        mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.movie_text_view);
    }
}
}
```

I want my UI to be like this
[image: The final UI should have a play button to the left of every movie trailer, an ImageView and a TextView in a row.]

With my code however the app looks like this:
[image: Where there should have been 3 trailer text views and 3 play button image views, I get this.]

Here is my xml resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_button_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movie_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to implement this without using different viewholders? Can it be done with a single ViewHolder?

I have seen ways to implement different View types with a RecyclerView, but I would prefer to keep my code as simple as possible.

Comment: Try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in LinearLayout

Comment: Great! However, this doesn't seem to affect the size of the image view (play button) despite having set a size for it in the xml. Why is that?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot comment on that. I'm posting my comment as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the height of LinearLayot to "wrap_content". and add gravity as "center_vertical"

change you item's layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_button_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movie_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, instead of `match_parent` in LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to change the height of the layout: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
 
2) For the ImageView set:

```
android:layout_width="10dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
```

(very small)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ConstraintLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Trailer 1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

That being said the easiest solution would be simply using "wrap_content" on your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_button_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Trailer 1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image: The output of this is]